# How to boost up netezza insert statement process

Tags: java, oracle, netezza

I am copying data from `Oracle` to `Netezza`. I have like thousands of rows and its taking too long to out all of these data into netezza using insert once for a row. How could I boost this up?

```
copyToChidDatabaseColumnInfo(rs.getString("OWNER"), rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"), rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME"));

// this is what it is within the copyToChidDatabaseColumnInfo method: 

PreparedStatement pstmt = ChildConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DATABASE_COLUMN_INFO (OWNER_NAME, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, SYSTEM_ID, PLATFORM) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
            pstmt.setString(1,owner);
            pstmt.setString(2,tbname);
            pstmt.setString(3,columnname);
            pstmt.setString(4,parentSYSTEM_ID);
            pstmt.setString(5,parentPlatform);
            pstmt.execute(); 
            pstmt.close();
```

Comment: Hint 1: google for "netezza bulk load".  Hint 2: consider changing the insert statement to insert a batch of rows at a time.

Comment: I am using an external csv file to push data into netezza. My table in netezza has 6 columns. First column must remain empty and the data from CSV file must fill in the reaming columns but all my data gets stored in the the first column of every row.

These are my column name: 'TABLE_NAME','COLUMN_NAME','SYSTEM_ID','PLATFORM'
"INSERT INTO DATABASE_TABLE_INFO SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL 'table_info.csv' USING (delimiter ',' REMOTESOURCE 'jdbc' LOGDIR 'C:\\temp' skiprows 1 maxerrors 0 fillrecord)";

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestion:

```
INSERT INTO DATABASE_COLUMN_INFO (nullcolumn, OWNER_NAME, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, SYSTEM_ID, PLATFORM)
SELECT null, OWNER_NAME, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, SYSTEM_ID, PLATFORM
FROM EXTERNAL 'table_info.csv'
(
OWNER_NAME varchar(500)
 ,TABLE_NAME  varchar(500)
 , COLUMN_NAME  varchar(500)
 , SYSTEM_ID  varchar(500)
 , PLATFORM  varchar(500)

)
USING (delimiter ',' REMOTESOURCE 'jdbc' LOGDIR 'C:\\temp' skiprows 1 maxerrors 0 fillrecord true)
```